# Auto complete using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Not sure whether it is possible, if I have the following code for autoComplete, how can I use this in jstl code to achieve the same? Or are there any other ways to achieve this?

```
<input type="text" id="department" name="department"/>

<script>
    $("#department").autocomplete("getdept.jsp",{minChars: 4});
</script>
```

and in `getdept.jsp`

```
DepartmentMB dept = new DepartmentMB ();
String query = request.getParameter("q");
List<String> dep = dept.getData(query);

Iterator<String> iterator = dep .iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String department = (String)iterator.next();
    String deptName=(String)it.next();
    out.println(deptName);

}
```

Comment: You can't do that with JSTL since it runs on view build time and it will run only once, instead handle the JSON response in your JavaScript and generate your HTML on that basis.

Comment: By the way, in your autocomplete jQuery method you should call a servlet instead of a JSP (assuming the code in *getdept.jsp* is inside a scriptlet).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes it will be a servlet, this is only for proof of concept.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza something like [this](http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2008/10/jquery-ajax-autocomplete-with-json-data/)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Or [this](http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/jquery-autocomplete-json-example.html) one?

Comment: One loads the data while writing, doing several calls to your server. The other loads all the data in client and have a local data source for autocompletion. Both can serve to your purposes, but you must decide which one to use. Make the proof of concept of both approaches, get your results and take the one that fits better for your requirements.